# Ошибка Test cmake run finished with errors Clion

Tags: clion

Установил *Clion* от *JetBrains*. Подтянул *MinGW*.

Однако при компиляции простейшей программы выдаёт вот такую простыню:

```
"F:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2017.2.1\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles" C:\Users\Алёша\CLionProjects\start
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 6.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 6.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: F:/Program Files/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: F:/Program Files/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe -- broken
CMake Error at F:/Program Files/JetBrains/CLion 2017.2.1/bin/cmake/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:51 (message):
The C compiler "F:/Program Files/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe" is not able to compile
a simple test program.

It fails with the following output:

Change Dir: C:/Users/РђР»С‘С€Р°/CLionProjects/start/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp



Run Build Command:"F:/PROGRA~2/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe"
"cmTC_b9c5c/fast"

F:/PROGRA~2/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f
CMakeFiles\cmTC_b9c5c.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_b9c5c.dir/build

mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory
'C:/Users/в””С‹в••В°СЂ/CLionProjects/start/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'


Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_b9c5c.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj

F:\PROGRA~2\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -o
CMakeFiles\cmTC_b9c5c.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj -c
C:\Users\в•ЁР в•Ёв•—в•¤РЎв•¤Р�в•Ёв–‘\CLionProjects\start\cmake-build-debug\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c


gcc.exe: error:
C:\Users\в•ЁР в•Ёв•—в•¤РЎв•¤Р�в•Ёв–‘\CLionProjects\start\cmake-build-debug\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c:
No such file or directory

gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files

compilation terminated.

CMakeFiles\cmTC_b9c5c.dir\build.make:64: recipe for target
'CMakeFiles/cmTC_b9c5c.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj' failed

mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_b9c5c.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj]
Error 1

mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory
'C:/Users/в””С‹в••В°СЂ/CLionProjects/start/cmake-build-
debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'


Makefile:125: recipe for target 'cmTC_b9c5c/fast' failed

mingw32-make.exe: *** [cmTC_b9c5c/fast] Error 2





CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)
```

Пожалуйста помогите разобраться, что нужно для работы ещё или почему ругается Clion. Спасибо за внимание!

Comment: MinGW подтянулась в File | Settings |Build, Execution, Deployment | Toolchains стоят все галочки внизу окна.

Comment: Попробуйте расположить проект в папке не содержащей русских символов и пробелов.

Answer (score 0):

У меня было с Clion тоже самое:

```
gcc.exe: error:
C:\Users\какие-то-кракозябры\ ...
No such file or directory
```

Положил проект в папку без кириллических символов, и всё заработало.