# Ошибка Test cmake run finished with errors в CLion

Tags: clion

Зашел в настройки, а там такая картина: Test cmake run finished with errors.

Как решить эту проблему?

Если нажать "more...", можно увидеть такое

> -- The C compiler identification is GNU 6.3.0
>   -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 6.3.0
>   -- Check for working C compiler: E:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe
>   -- Check for working C compiler: E:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe -- broken CMake Error at E:/CLion
>   2018.2.5/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:52 (message):   The C compiler
>
> ```
> "E:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe"
> ```
>
> is not able to compile a simple test program.
>
> It fails with the following output:
>
> ```
> Change Dir: C:/Users/Р•РІРіРµРЅРёР№/AppData/Local/Temp/cmake_check_environment1/_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>
> Run Build Command:"E:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe" "cmTC_db37f/fast"
> E:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_db37f.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_db37f.dir/build
> mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/в”јС‚СѓС…СЌС€С‰/AppData/Local/Temp/cmake_check_environment1/_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
> Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_db37f.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj
> E:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe    -o CMakeFiles\cmTC_db37f.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj   -c
> ```
>
> C:\Users\в•ЁРҐв•Ёв–“в•Ёв”‚в•Ёв•Ўв•Ёв•њв•Ёв••в•Ёв•Ј\AppData\Local\Temp\cmake_check_environment1_build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c
>       gcc.exe: error: C:\Users\в•ЁРҐв•Ёв–“в•Ёв”‚в•Ёв•Ўв•Ёв•њв•Ёв••в•Ёв•Ј\AppData\Local\Temp\cmake_check_environment1_build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c:
>   No such file or directory
>       gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
>       compilation terminated.
>       CMakeFiles\cmTC_db37f.dir\build.make:64: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_db37f.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj' failed
>       mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_db37f.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj] Error 1
>       mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/в”јС‚СѓС…СЌС€С‰/AppData/Local/Temp/cmake_check_environment1/_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>       Makefile:120: recipe for target 'cmTC_db37f/fast' failed
>       mingw32-make.exe: *** [cmTC_db37f/fast] Error 2
>
> CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project. Call
>   Stack (most recent call first):   CMakeLists.txt:1 (project)
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! See also "C:/Users/Р•РІРіРµРЅРёР№/AppData/Local/Temp/cmake_check_environment1/_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
>   See also
>   "C:/Users/Р•РІРіРµРЅРёР№/AppData/Local/Temp/cmake_check_environment1/_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
>
> Error code: 1

Comment: возможно стоит попробовать переместить проект в папку, путь до которой не содержит русские символы.

Comment: а можно ли как-то изменить название существующей, если это папка пользователя?как обычную я не могу ее переименовать

Comment: [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/712597/clion-не-компилирует)